# How to call Layouts in flutter?

Tags: android, function, layout, flutter, routes

I'm new in Flutter.

I have a question

How to call layouts in flutter ?

I've been create some layouts that contains a lot of widget.
It's not right if I make every code inside 1 file.
so I decide to put the code for the widgets in every 1 layouts file.

and I dont know how to call them in the home-page.dart that I create.

I mean, if I push THIS (i.e page1.dart), then the page1.dart is appear.
thought that file (page1.dart) is in other directory (not inside lib dir).

I dont know. am I should use ROUTES ?
but I dont know how.

would you like to teach me ?

..............

here are. I have TabBar like this in my home_page.dart:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:coba/second.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String tag = 'home-page';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "MySampleApplication",
        home: new DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: new Scaffold( 
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text("Hello Flutter App"), 
              bottom: new TabBar(                 
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  new Tab(text: "First Tab"),
                  new Tab(text: "Second Tab"),
                  new Tab(text: "Third Tab"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            body: new TabBarView( 
                children: <Widget>[
                   new Text("You've Selected First"),
                   new SecondWidget(),
                   new ThirdWidget(),
                ]
            )
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
class SecondWidget extends StatelessWidget {   
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) =>
              second(data: 'Hello there from the first page!'),
        ),
  }
}

class ThirdWidget extends StatelessWidget { 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('halooo'),
        Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any name that you want (generally, we have seen `xxxScreen.dart` or `xxxPage.dart`, but it is totally up to you).

Import your "destiny" page using in "origin" page using `import`:

```
    import 'package:myproject/myPageScreen.dart';
```

Flutter offers 3 options:

1. Using [Navigator](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics):

```
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
          SecondPage(data: 'Hello there from the first page!'),
    ),
```

2. Using [Named](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes) routes:

Declare you routes in `MaterialApp`:

```
MaterialApp(
  // Start the app with the "/" named route. In our case, the app will start
  // on the FirstScreen Widget
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    // When we navigate to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen Widget
    '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
    // When we navigate to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen Widget
    '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
  },
);
```

And then use named route with Navigator:

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
}
```

3. Using `onGenerateRoute`:

Declare this property on your `MaterialApp`:

```
    return MaterialApp(
      // Initially display FirstPage
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: _getRoute,
    );
```

And create your *route generator* :

```
    final args = settings.arguments;
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => 
          FirstPage());
      case '/second':
        // Validation of correct data type
        if (args is String) {
           return MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (_) => SecondPage(
           data: args,
        ),
      );
    }
```

You can create your router as another file to help to organize your project.

Comment: and what is the 3rd way by the way ?

Comment: if I use 

Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
          SecondPage(data: 'Hello there from the first page!'),
    ),

where is the part in that line for me to put the xxxpage.dart ?

mr. @Rubens Melo

Comment: at beginning of file

Comment: I've updated my Question sir, btw.

nah can I use that for multiple layouts ?
so If I have 10 layouts, I've to declare all of that layouts each file in import, import, import, import, etc ?

Comment: yep. you have to import every one.

Comment: well Okay. I understand now. I've check the green checklist for your explanation.
thank you so much @Rubens Melo. :)